# Using IIS App (Network Service - Windows Auth Only) - Not accessing SQL server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, iis

When I run my application locally it can connect to the remote SQL server and edit the database fine however, when adding the application to the IIS App Pool as a NetworkService with Windows Auth. only, every sql request doesn't go through.

Conn String:

```
connectionString="Data Source=ServerIP;Initial Catalog=DB_NAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=PASS" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I have verified that this conn string works from localhost to access and modify the remote database.

When I publish though, the pages load but anytime I attempt to access/edit the database, my code fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it myself. The issue was that when I went to get my connection string from the web config I used:

```
WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

When I needed to change it to:

```
WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
```